# fatal: Authentication failed for <URL> not asking for credentials

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy the React application as Azure web app . (doing this by local git) .  when i did run the command git push azure master , it asked me for the username and password . authentication .I Reset the password and when i run that command again its not prompting the credentials dialog instead fails the authentication , any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows, you may go into Control Panel => User Accounts => Manage your credentials => Windows Credentials, and then find corresponding saved credential to delete the wrong one.